# Можно ли изменить шрифт в тэге <title> (Заголовок, не подсказка)?

Tags: html, шрифты

Можно ли как-то изменить шрифт во вкладке страницы?

Comment: [enSo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649610/can-we-set-style-to-title-tag-in-header)

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если его отобразить на странице, то да. А если серьёзно, нет :)

```css
head, title { display: block; }
title { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<title>Test</title>
```